# An intriguing relation between two alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is another intriguing formula coming from Ramanujan's letter to G. H. Hardy dated 16th Jan 1913 $$\frac{\log 1}{\sqrt{1}} - \frac{\log 3}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{\log 5}{\sqrt{5}} - \cdots = \left(\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\gamma}{2} + \frac{\log 2\pi}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} - \cdots\right)$$ where $$\gamma = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} - \log n\right)$$ is the Euler's constant.

This seems really a different kind of series dealing with $\sqrt{n}$ in the denominator and is so unlike the usual series for $\log (1 + x)$ or $\arctan x$ or even Abel's function $\sum x^{n}/n^{2}$. Please help me out in proving the above identity. Any reference having a proof would also be of great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes straight from the functional equation for the [Dirichlet beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) $\beta(s)$ (proved by Hardy in a very clever way), since:
$$ \frac{d}{ds}\frac{1}{n^s}=-\frac{\log n}{n^s}.$$

Comment: From your answer it seems there is an relation between $\beta(s)$ and its derivative $\beta'(s)$ which involves somehow $\gamma$.

Comment: Ok I get that. We need to differentiate the relation between $\beta(1 - s)$ and $\beta(s)$ given in wikipedia article. Let me know if I am on right track.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: exactly.

Comment: I will work out my details on paper. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: you're welcome.

Comment: I am able to get the relation finally between $\beta'(1/2)$ and $\beta(1/2)$ and it solves the problem. Do you have a reference to Hardy's proof of the functional equation?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: a very interesting overview is given by Terence Tao in its blog (https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/254a-supplement-3-the-gamma-function-and-the-functional-equation-optional/)

Comment: I have given my pending upvote.