# Closed-form expression for $\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(4n+3)^{1/(4n+3)}}{(4n+5)^{1/(4n+5)}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, infinite-product

I have recently come across this infinite product, and I was wondering what methods I could use to express the product in closed-form (if it is even possible):

$$\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(4n+3)^{1/(4n+3)}}{(4n+5)^{1/(4n+5)}}=\dfrac{3^{1/3}}{5^{1/5}}\cdot \dfrac{7^{1/7}}{9^{1/9}}\cdot\dfrac{11^{1/11}}{13^{1/13}}\cdot\dfrac{15^{1/15}}{17^{1/17}}\cdot\dotsb$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give the context? Many times, the subject surrounding it is a hint to where to start thinking.

Comment: Taking the logarithm is usually a good start to convert the product to a sum. Then the powers can be brought down.

Comment: Yes, it has a closed form. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3032875/prove-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n1-ln2n12n1-pi-4-gamma-ln-p

Comment: @Chrystomath I was attempting to solve the following: Choose $x$, $y$, and $z$ from $(0,1)$. Find the probability that $\frac{x}{yz}$ rounds to an even number. This infinite product appeared in a part of the final answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\exp\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{\log(4n+3)}{4n+3}-\frac{\log(4n+5)}{4n+5}\right)=\exp\left[-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi_4(n)\log(n)}{n}\right]$$
equals
$$\lim_{s\to 1^+}\exp\left[\frac{d}{ds}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi_4(n)}{n^s}\right]=\exp\beta'(1)$$
with $\beta$ being [Dirichlet's beta function](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funzione_beta_di_Dirichlet). According to equation [(18)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletBetaFunction.html) the closed form is
$$ \exp\,\left[\frac{\pi}{4}\left(\gamma+\log\frac{4\pi^3}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^4}\right)\right].$$
A derivation can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833700/how-are-values-of-the-dirichlet-beta-function-derivative-derived).