# Limit of sequence for an alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit of the sequence $y_n = \sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\frac{\ln{k}}{k}$.
I have tested the limit for convergence using Lebiniz's test for alternating series and it is indeed convergent. I can't seem to figure out how to get to the answer, though.

Comment: Tried [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B%28%E2%88%921%29%5Ek*Log%5Bk%5D%2Fk%2C+%7Bk%2C2%2CInfinity%7D%5D)?

Comment: @gt6989b I don't have a premium account and I need to know how to solve it, not just the end value

Comment: Likely the last term in that answer comes from
$$
\int\frac{\ln x}{x} dx = \frac{\ln^2x}{2},
$$
not completely sure but would try to manipulate the odd and even terms separately

Comment: Did you consider integrating $y= \frac {\ln(2x)}{2x}-\frac {\ln(2x+1)}{2x+1}$ from $[1, \infty] $

Comment: You may also be interested in a similar but reasonably complicated sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1}\dfrac{\log(2k+1)}{2k+1}$ which is discussed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2890499/72031).

Comment: This question is presumably difficult for your level. Are you sure the value of the limit was requested ?

Answer (score 5):

Using Euler-Maclaurin we can show existence of

$$C= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\log k}{k} - \int_1^n\frac{\ln x}{x} \, dx\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\log k}{k} - \frac{(\ln n)^2}{2}\right)$$

Note that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \frac{\ln k}{k} = -\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\ln k}{k} - \frac{(\ln(2n))^2}{2}\right) + 2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\ln(2k)}{2k} - \frac{(\ln(2n))^2}{2}$$

Using $\ln(2n) = \ln 2 + \ln  n$, the RHS reduces to

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \frac{\ln k}{k} = -\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{\ln k}{k} - \frac{(\ln(2n))^2}{2}\right) +\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln k}{k} - \frac{(\ln n)^2}{2}\right) \\+ \ln 2\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \ln n \right) - \frac{(\ln 2)^2}{2}$$

Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{\ln k}{k} = -C + C + \gamma \ln 2 - \frac{(\ln 2)^2}{2}= \ln 2 \left(\gamma - \frac{\ln 2}{2} \right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is another technique. Let $$f(s) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n^s}$$ then we have $$f(s) - \zeta(s) = - \frac{\zeta(s)}{2^{s-1}}$$ or $$f(s) =(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$$ The desired limit in question is $f'(1)$. Differentiate the above with respect to $s$ and let $s\to 1$. This will give the desired result.

---

I later found the same approach given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/253561/72031).

---

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100809/72031) justifies the appearance of $\gamma$ as a constant term in Laurent series for $\zeta(s) $ and thereby makes the approach in this answer non-circular (see comments below).

Comment: Funny how gamma emerges here (+1).

Comment: @RRL: There is another similar result by Ramanujan regarding Dirichlet beta function. See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1284941/72031).

Comment: @RRL: I later checked [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176834/72031) and it appears that the occurrence of $\gamma$ as a constant term in Laurent series for $\zeta(s) $ is a consequence of the fact being asked to prove here. So unless there are other methods to evaluate the limit $\lim_{s\to 1^{+}}\zeta(s)-\frac{1}{s-1}$ this answer of mine is circular.